# How to filter by date with sqlalchemy

Tags: python, mysql, sql, sqlalchemy

After I import the modules:

```
import datetime, uuid
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy import Column, ForeignKey, Integer, String, DateTime, create_engine, literal
```

I proceed by connecting to db:

```
Base = declarative_base()
session = scoped_session(sessionmaker())
engine = create_engine('mysql://root:pass@localhost/testdb', echo=False)
session.remove()
session.configure(bind=engine, autoflush=False, expire_on_commit=False)
```

I define and create MyObject's table:

```
class MyObject(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'myobjects'
    uuid = Column(String(64), primary_key=True, unique=True)
    created = Column(DateTime, nullable=False) 

    def __init__ (self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.uuid = str(uuid.uuid4()).replace('-','').lower()
        self.created = datetime.datetime.utcnow()

Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

I create 10 `MyObject` entities:

```
for i in range(10):
    obj = MyObject()
    session.add(obj)
    session.commit()
```

I query all the entities by printing their date created:

```
objects = session.query(MyObject).all()
for obj in objects:
    print obj.created
```

prints:

```
2017-01-05 17:22:21
2017-01-05 17:22:21
.
.
.
2017-01-05 17:22:43
```

**Question:**

How to query by filtering only those entities that were not created on exactly '2017-01-05 17:22:43'?

I have tried this:

```
result = session.query(MyObject).filter(MyObject.created!='2017-01-05 17:22:43').all()
```

But it returns all the objects filtering nothing...

Comment: By default, utcnow() includes microseconds.. are you sure those aren't getting stored in the database? What does the raw record look like?

Comment: Could you post the result of `print str(query)` so we can see what SQL is being generated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To compare `datetimes` you will need to convert your `string` to `datetime` objects. For e.g. to convert the string `2016-10-20` to `datetime` you can do so:

```
from datetime import datetime
print datetime.strptime('2016-10-20', '%Y-%m-%d')
```

For your question if you are trying to check if the column `created` doesn't match the time `2017-01-05 17:22:43` then we first convert to `datetime` object in our query:

```
from datetime import datetime
search_created = datetime.strptime('2017-01-05 17:22:43', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
result = session.query(MyObject).filter(MyObject.created!=search_created).all()
```

You can look up more information on `strftime` and `strptime` over [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior).

Comment: This is incorrect. Datetime comparisons can be made using date strings... So long as they match the format in the database field.

Comment: @dizzyf Are you sure it's wrong? Kiran.koduru compares datetimes, not strings

Comment: @PiotrDawidiuk In python, comparing datetimes requires `datetime` objects. But to filter by datetimes in sqlalchemy, string comparisons work just fine... it's not necessary to cast them to an actual python `datetime` object first. This answer is misleading.